# How do I get access to the drawable?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, xamarin

I have a layout as such (which I use for a fragment):

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="fill_parent"
   android:minWidth="25px"
   android:minHeight="25px">
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/Text_Value"
    android:text="0"
    android:textSize="32dp"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/PlaySquareShape"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

I have this shape as the background for the TextView in the above layout:

```
  <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:shape="rectangle">
        <solid android:color="#ffffff" />
        <stroke android:width="1dip" android:color="#4fa5d5"/>
  </shape>
```

I need to change the colors for the drawable. How do I access it from code?

I basically have many instances of the fragment displayed, and I need to access the background drawable from a specific fragment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this:

```
View v = findViewById(R.id.Text_Value);
ShapeDrawable d = (ShapeDrawable) v.getBackground();
```

Or, if you have a reference to a specific a fragment:

```
View v = frag.getView().findViewById(R.id.Text_Value);
```

Comment: Perfect! I'll try it. Thanks  :)  I'm still new at this.

Comment: It worked!! The only difference is that my background was a GradientDrawable  :)